# Seaborn clustermap not displaying all row annotations

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

[image: heatmap picture]

I am creating a clustermap of a list of 529 genes. For some reason not all the genes in the index of the dataframe are being displayed in the clustermap. I've attached an image showing the issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
def create_heatmap(dataframe, title):
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
sns_plot = sns.clustermap(dataframe,mask=False,row_cluster=True,linewidth=.05,
                          linecolor="grey",col_cluster=False,standard_scale=0
                          ,cmap="Greys",square=True,figsize=(12,(.2*(len(dataframe.index)))))
sns_plot.savefig("{}.png".format(title))
return sns_plot
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You would probably want to use the `yticklabels` keyword argument to label all rows in the heatmap:

```
sns.clustermap(...,  yticklabels=True)
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Comment: How come this is not written in the seaborn [official documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html)?